# figure next to a barplot

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

Okay, I tried a lot of things and can't really find it anywhere. Is there a simple example code for how to put a picture next to a graph?

I tried to play around with `hspace` and `vspace` as well as an example of having two plots next to each other but replacing it by a figure is not possible for me at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using the little yet powerful [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package (which has a better interaction with `hyperref` than `subfig`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=3in}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{picture} 
  \caption{A picture}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot    {x^2 * sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A plot}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The relative vertical alignment can be controlled by using the optional argument of the `subfigure` environment.

In the above approach I assumed that the figure and plot should be treated as subfigures; if this is not the case and both should be considered as independent figures, then two side-by-side minipages can be an option; the `\captionof` command could be used to produce the captions and an additional `figure` environment could be used to make the whole arrangement float:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=3in}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{picture} 
  \captionof{figure}{A picture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot    {x^2 * sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{A plot}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Other advantages of `subcaption` are that you can very easily customize the font and enumeration style of (a), (b), etc (I know that Gonzalo knows this, thought I'd mention it for the OP)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a job for the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package. Examples can be found in its [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf).

A quick example using TikZ to draw a very simple plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
  \centering
  \subfloat[Your image]{\rule{30pt}{30pt}}\qquad
  \subfloat[Your plot]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[gray, very thin] (0,0) grid (3,3);
      \draw (0,0) node[below left] {0} -- ++(3,0) node [right] {x};
      \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,3) node [above] {y};
      \draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Image next to plot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

looks like this:

[image: subfig example]

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing, a simple `tabular` can do the trick. If you want your figures to have separate captions you can use the `\captionof` command from the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to insert them.  I've used the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package to format the table cells so that the content is centred vertically. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=3in}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{M{2in}M{3in}}
\includegraphics{picture} & 
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
\addplot    {x^2 * sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\captionof{figure}{A picture} & \captionof{figure}{A plot}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]